# Should Count() of an IEnumerable be avoided?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

In general, I am using a `List` and then returning them as `IEnumerable` when I no longer need to update them.

However, I ran into an issue where I actually need to enumerate through them but first need to know the count.

Will `IEnumerable` enumerate every item and find the count (O(N)), or will it rely on `List`'s Count property (O(1))?

Also, what if the `IEnumerable` is the result of a LINQ query?

Comment: You can cast your `List` to an `IReadOnlyCollection`. It states your intent better and also has a `Count` property.

Comment: I totally agree with @AndreySarafanov. And you still have the benefits of covariance (`IReadOnlyCollection<out T>`). Of course there is also `IReadOnlyList<out T>` if you may need (or want to expose) indexer access.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Will IEnumerable enumerate every item and find the count (O(N)), or will it rely on List's Count property (O(1))?

It will use the `Count` property. Basically the implementation checks whether or not the object implements `ICollection<T>` or `ICollection`, and calls the relevant `Count` property if so. (The use of the non-generic `ICollection` was only introduced in .NET 4; in .NET 3.5 it only noticed `ICollection<T>`.)

It's only [*documented*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338038(v=vs.100).aspx) for `ICollection<T>`, however:

> If the type of source implements `ICollection<T>`, that implementation is used to obtain the count of elements. Otherwise, this method determines the count.

Comment: For reference, here is the actual implementation: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,41ef9e39e54d0d0b

Comment: @Dia Holy ****! I didn't realize .NET source code was available!

Comment: @Dai: Or https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs

Comment: @Jon Skeet, but isn't it an implementation detail? It's not a contract for `IEnumerable`, so could be changed easily.

Comment: @Vladislav: `IEnumerable` doesn't matter - it's documented in `Enumerable.Count`, although only for the generic interface. Will add that to the answer.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, hurried with my question, it deals with extension method contract, you are right, of course. But, nevertheless, this approach seems unstable. Implementation of method, which returns `IEnumerable` will change sometime, but no one will notice increased algorithm complexity.

Comment: @Vladislav: That's a matter of not relying on the actual type returned by the method - *that* may be an implementation detail, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: @Vladislav: IMHO, .NET should have defined an enumeration interface which would have made it practical for things like the return from `Enumerable.Concat` to implement a `Count` method which would only have to iterate through constituents that didn't support `Count` themselves, so as to avoid the performance issues you describe, but the fact that LINQ seems popular even without it suggests that such issues don't pose too much of a problem to many people.