# How to do a count on an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#

I want to be able to test a count of obj below but not able to do so.
when I mouse over obj it shows a count of 3

```
    <IEnumerable<File> obj = await _mytester.cleanup(myitems)
```

why cant i do this?

```
    if(obj.count > 0)
```

The liine above is giving me an error

Comment: You could call the `Count()` extension method... `if (obj.Count() > 0) ...`. Tho you will probably want to use `Any()` instead to check if the sequence is not empty. `if (obj.Any()) ...`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815853/should-count-of-an-ienumerable-be-avoided

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that because `count` doesn't exist on `IEnumerable` and that's by design.

You can use `IEnumerable.Count()` like this:

`if (obj.Count() > 0)`

But that's horribly inefficient since you're really just checking if there's anything there.

You're better off doing this:

`if (obj.Any())`

Both of these are provided by LINQ extension methods.

It's very important to note that `Count()` is iterating through all elements and is nowhere near as efficient as something like `ICollection.Count`

Comment: Also there's no reason for an `IEnumerable` to have a finite count anyway.

Comment: You will need to add `using System.Linq` in order to access these methods in .NET 3.5 and higher, but I thoroughly agree with the use of `.Any()`.